# Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64') error even though dropped null data?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, statistics

I am trying to do a simple linear regression.  I've made a data frame in pandas and then typed.  This doesn't remove any rows so I assume there are no missing values.

`df.dropna()` # remove all rows with missing data

Then I ran the following code to create NumPy arrays for 2 columns that I wish to run my linear regression between.

```
`Amy_Dif_Num = df.iloc[:, 10].values.reshape(-1, 1)`  

Amy_Dif_Num.shape
```

`Pain_Int_Num = df.iloc[:, 3].values.reshape(-1, 1)`  # values converts it into a numpy array
Pain_Int_Num.shape

Then when I run my regression, it errors that I have a missing value.  What am I missing here?  Please help.

```
X = Pain_Int_Num
Y = Amy_Dif_Num
np.isnan(X).any()



linear_regressor = LinearRegression()  # create object for the class
linear_regressor.fit(X, Y)  # perform linear regression
Y_pred = linear_regressor.predict(X)  # make predictions

ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

When I run

`np.isnan(X).any()` #this comes out True

How do I remove this null value whilst also continuing to have the same number of columns in each NumPy array?  Please help.

Also, why didn't my `df.dropna()` code work earlier?

Comment: `dropna` does not work in place by default, use the argument `inplace=True`. Or are you setting a new dataframe like `df2 = df.dropna()`?

Comment: Thanks!  That's perfect! I knew it was something obvious.